# How to clear cart programmatically using a cart ID

Tags: magento2, cart

I have a custom module which, among other things, when installed will create a page. I want to pass a cart ID (encrypted) to this page as a param and then get this cart ID and delete. This needs to be be done via an ID, **not** via session.

This is what I have so far (effectively only creates the page):

```
<?php
    namespace Zitec\Concierge\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

    class AddCartClearingPage implements DataPatchInterface
    {
        /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
        private $moduleDataSetup;

        /** @var PageFactory */
        private $pageFactory;
        private \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request;
        protected  $_modelCart;
        protected $_checkoutSession;

        /**
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
         * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
            PageFactory $pageFactory
        ) {
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
            $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
            $this->request = $request;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            $pageContent = <<<HTML
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Clearing Cart</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    HTML;

            $pageData = [
                'title' => 'Title',
                'identifier' => 'title',
                'page_layout' => 'identifier',
                'content_heading' => 'Clearing Cart',
                'content' => $pageContent,
                'is_active' => 1,
                'stores' => [\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID],
                'sort_order' => 11
            ];

            $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
            $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
            $page->setData($pageData)->save();

            $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();

            /**
             * Clearing the cart
             */
            # Not sure this is working as expected
            $cartID = $this->request->getParams();
            $cart = $this->_modelCart;
            # I dont think this is correct either
            $quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
            foreach($quoteItems as $item)
            {
                $cart->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish the remaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **try this code**

```
<?php

namespace Zitec\Concierge\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCartClearingPage implements DataPatchInterface
{
    .................................................
    protected $quoteFactory;
    protected $itemmodel;
    .................................................

    public function __construct(
        .................................................
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        Item $itemmodel,
        .................................................
    ) {
        .................................................
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->itemmodel = $itemmodel;
        .................................................
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        .................................................
        .................................................
        
        $quoteId = 2; // pass your quote Id here
        $quoteData = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        $allItems = $quoteData->getAllItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item)
        {
            $cartItemId = (int) $item->getItemId();
            $itemObj = $this->itemmodel->load($cartItemId);
            $itemObj->delete();
        }
        $quoteData->delete();
        
        .................................................
        .................................................
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Help You.***

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all the item from cart or want to disable current cart than you can just set

```
$cart->setIsActive(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear shopping cart using below code

```
<?php
namespace Zitec\Concierge\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
class AddCartClearingPage implements DataPatchInterface
{
    protected $_modelCart;
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
         Cart $modelCart,
         CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) 
    {
       $this->_modelCart = $modelCart;
       $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $cartId=123;
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
        $visitems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($visitems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $this->_modelCart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
    }
}
```

you can also clear cart using single line

> $this->_modelCart->truncate();

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
class Clearcart extends Action
{
    protected $_modelCart;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession, Cart $modelCart)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_modelCart = $modelCart;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $cart = $this->_modelCart;
        $quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $cart->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
        }
    }
}
```